# Differential equation to describe an RC circuit with a sine wave

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, sine

[image]

In this image Vin is a sine wave , sin(ωt), and I am trying to get the differential equation that I will then be able to solve.

I am having troubles trying to find the current through the power supply and I no sure weather I am not taking the correct approach to solving this.

Comment: You still need to ask a question. Saying you are having troubles finding current through the power supply is meaningless for two reasons (a) What power supply are you talking about and (b) it still isn't a question; it's a statement. In addition, if you changed it into "can anyone explain why I'm having troubles...." then, it does become a question but, it's a question that nobody here will be able to answer because nobody will know why you have this trouble. So, if you plan to go this route, show what work you've done so far so that people can "see" where you are struggling.

Comment: Let the current be \$i\$, then write KVL for the loop, given that the voltage across the capacitor is \$\frac{1}{C}\int i\:dt\$. Solve the resultant differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

The image below shows methods to find expressions for magnitude and phase of gain of RC low pass filter:

[image]